# Is there a Legal Requirement for Computer Companies to Include an Operating System when Selling a PC?

Tags: software, business, commerce, hardware

I asked a company if they could sell me a PC without an installed Operating System, as I plan to install my own.  Their response was that *"We have to legally include a OS with all of our systems. So we include Windows 10."*  It surprised me that this would be a legal issue rather than a company policy.

The company is based in Utah.  Is this an actual legal requirement by law?  Why?  Could it be to protect consumers?  Would it protect the company from liability?  Is it likely part of a contract they are in?  Or is this a misunderstanding by customer service?

I didn't find anything with a cursory web search.  (I am a new poster, so any critiques of my question are welcome.)

Answer (score 8):

### No

AFAIK there is no such legal requirement.

Why this company told you there was I can’t speculate. But I will.

There may be under contract with MicroSoft to put their OS on every box they sell - that would be a legal requirement. Or the just don’t sell boxes without this and they employee told you it was a legal obligation to get out of the conversation.

Comment: Some more background (possibly rather out of date): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundling_of_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: It's not clear whether this is the retailer or manufacturer, on the retail side they probably contractually have to sell the boxed computer as they receive it, and the manufacturer probably has licensing deals with Microsoft that include exclusivity, at least for specific models.

Comment: ...Didn't the courts rule at some point that it's illegal to _require_ an OEM to put your company's OS on it?

Comment: It would be  contractually required to get a discounted price on the OS.

Comment: There is the obvious fact that if you buy this computer, unpack it, and plug it in, then it doesn't work. That's exactly what you wanted to buy. But it would be conceivable that there are laws making this illegal: That an item you buy must work as it comes out of the box.

Comment: @gnasher729 not if you buy components. You didn't buy a computer, you bought a component for a computer.

Comment: @gnasher729 If that was true, that would require every desktop computer to come bundled with a monitor.

Comment: @gnasher729 - But it does work. You unpack it, plug it in, and instal the operating system of your choice - which is why you bought a computer without an operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any legal requirement to include software with hardware. If they insist on providing an operating system, tell them to include Linux, as this costs $0 so you do not need to pay for the Windows license.

As Dale M says, if they have a contract with a provider to force certain software onto their customers, that does mean that they specifically have a contractual obligation to give you that bloatware. Then again, you have no legal obligation to purchase from them.

Comment: "tell them to include Ubuntu Linux, as this costs $0" No, Ubuntu [charges OEMs a fee](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/partners): "There are no royalties, only a per unit service fee covering the engineering certification, maintenance, quality assurance, third-party licensing fees and Canonical consulting costs." Additionally, the hardware has to be certified for Ubuntu. The free option is usually FreeDOS.

Comment: OK fair enough, bad specific example, however, my main point still stands - there are $0 alternatives to Windows that remove the need to pay for a Windows licence.